# Write a function that takes a string and replaces two consecutive letters in a "Double*" pattern

Tags: java

Example:

1. "hello" - "heDoubleLo"
2. "bookkeeper" -  "bDoubleODoubleKDoubleEper"
   Note that after "Double" the character becomes uppercase. That's the problem

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(stringTransform("hello"));
        System.out.println(stringTransform("bookkeeper"));
    }
    public static String stringTransform(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("([a-z])\\1","Double" + "$1".toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Expected result:
heDoubleLo
bDoubleODoubleKDoubleEper

The resulting result:
heDoublelo
bDoubleoDoublekDoubleeper

Comment: toUpperCase() -> make the char to uppercase !!!

Comment: Hint: `"$1"`.toUpperCase() is still `"$1"`. You're going to want `Matcher.replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)`

Comment: @JonSkeet and there I was, writing that myself...

Comment: This reads like a homework; are you allowed to use Regular Expressions? Usually these kind of assignments want you to use old-school String manipulation...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately*, you can't use `String.replaceAll` for this. That's because `toUpperCase()` is called on `"$1"`, not each actual match.

You can use `Matcher.replaceAll(Function<MatchResult, String>)` for this (with thanks to Jon Skeet):

```java
// Pattern is immutable, so creating shared instances is good practice
private static final Pattern STRING_TRANSFORM_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([a-z])\\1");

public static String stringTransform(String str) {
    return STRING_TRANSFORM_PATTERN
            .matcher(str)
            .replaceAll(match -> "Double" + match.group(1).toUpperCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* class, utilizing the *[replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function))* method.

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z])\\1");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
return m.replaceAll(x -> "Double" + m.group(1).toUpperCase());
```

Or, the *[appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuilder,java.lang.String))* and *[appendTail](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuilder,java.lang.String))* methods.

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z])\\1");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(s, "Double" + m.group(1).toUpperCase());
m.appendTail(s);
return s.toString();
```

Alternately, use a *loop* to find each occurrence of *"Double"*, and uppercase the succeeding character.

```java
str = str.replaceAll("([a-z])\\1","Double$1");
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(str);
int o = -1;
while ((o = s.indexOf("Double", o + 1)) != -1)
    s.setCharAt(o + 6, Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(o + 6)));
return s.toString();
```

Or, a less practical approach would be to try each *double a – z*.

```java
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    str = str.replaceAll(c + "" + c, "Double" + Character.toUpperCase(c));
return str;
```

Output

```
heDoubleLo
bDoubleODoubleKDoubleEper
```

Comment: I started writing code using `appeldReplacement` and `appendTail`, but then Jon Skeet mentioned `Matcher.replaceAll` in his comment. That allows you to do the same without the explicit matcher loop. You can see in my answer how easy the code can become.